# Cómo puedo cambiar el fondo de las opciones cuando se despliega el <select>?

Tags: html, css, select, style

No puedo cambiar el fondo del desplegable de un select. El background-color en el select le da estilo cuando éste no está activado, y el darle background-color a las options hace que se vea horrible, no estila el desplegable completo. Dejo ejemplo de lo que hice y como quedó

```
<select style="left: 19.9%; border: solid 2px #a21b1b71;" class="position-relative mb-3 font-josefin-sans bordeaux-color bg-light-black" name="edad" id="">
                            <option style="background-color: black;" value="" disabled selected>Edad</option>
                            <option style="background-color: black;" value="niño">Menor de 15 años</option>
                            <option style="background-color: black;" value="adolescente">Entre 15 y 19 años</option>
                            <option style="background-color: black;" value="joven">Entre 20 y 28 años</option>
                            <option style="background-color: black;" value="adulto">Entre 29 y 45 años</option>
                            <option style="background-color: black;" value="adultoMayor">Más de 45 años</option>
                        </select>
```

Y así de feo me queda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven queda la opción deshabilitada y una parte al final sin el color.

Ignorar lo feo que pueda estar mi código, recién arranco en esto!

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el selector

`select option {}`

o el sub selector de atributo

```
select option[value="adolecente"] {
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
}
```

lo mismo para el "disabled"

```
select option:disabled { /* estilos... */}
```

y tu html

```
<select style="left: 19.9%; border: solid 2px #a21b1b71;" class="position-relative mb-3 font-josefin-sans bordeaux-color bg-light-black" name="edad" id="">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Edad</option>
    <option value="niño">Menor de 15 años</option>
    <option value="adolescente">Entre 15 y 19 años</option>
    <option value="joven">Entre 20 y 28 años</option>
    <option value="adulto">Entre 29 y 45 años</option>
    <option value="adultoMayor">Más de 45 años</option>
</select>
```

Puedes checar un [ejemplo aquí](https://codepen.io/joseph-sx-the-bashful/pen/abwbxLM)

y si te refieres al borde gris te recomiendo uses un ["css reset"](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: Muchas gracias! miré el ejemplo y simplemente probando con "background" en vez de "background-color" me quedó bien. Graciaaaas :)